# How to fix VirtualBox/disable Hyper V?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

For Context: I'm running Windows 10 Home Version 10.0.18363 Build 18363

So I use VirtualBox fairly frequently for a class. Yesterday, I installed Docker on my computer. This broke VirtualBox. More specifically, VirtualBox will start, I can start a virtual machine, I will get a boot screen, and then the screen will go black instead of booting up. I uninstalled Docker as soon as I made the connection between the two.

I've done some research. My understanding is the Docker enables HyperV, which prevents VirtualBox from running and causes the exact problem that I'm describing.

Here's my issue: One of the main ways of disabling HyperV is going into Turn Windows Features on and off. The problem is that the screenshots for this screen do not match mine. I have tried using Powershell to disable HyperV and that hasn't worked.

### Screenshots

My Screen:

Checking or unchecking Virtual Machine Platform and Windows Hypervisor Platform have no effect.

[image]

Other People's Screen:

[image]

Comment: Windows Home does not have Hyper-V, perhaps this could help https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/disable-hyperv-in-win-10-home/2f81ddf6-e098-45e9-ab2a-7b7529dc8ea4?page=3

Comment: Thank you for this. That thread really helped. Turns out that Hyper-V (or something like it) was enabled on my computer the solution was cmd-->Run as admin--> bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off

Comment: You're welcome :D

Answer (score 2):

I run into the same issue too running the same windows edition, I tried everything but it didn't work, I finally tried changing the launch typesetting for hyper-v from **Auto** to **Off** and it finally worked.

Check out my answer on this post to see how to achieve that: [Can't install Android Emulator for AMD Processors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59549988/cant-install-android-emulator-for-amd-processors/67046272#67046272)

To check if Hyper-V is disabled, open cmd as administrator and type `systeminfo.exe` you should see this result

[image: Command Prompt Screenshot]