# Android studio emulator can't run

Tags: android-studio

Hey so my emulator isnt running when trying to run my application. I am using AMD thats probably why cause it works fine on my friends computer (intel).

**This is the error:**
[image]

What I have done:
I have tried the solutions here: [Can't install Android Emulator for AMD Processors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59549988/cant-install-android-emulator-for-amd-processors).
I have turned off my SVM Mode and disable windows features that implictly enable hyper-v. I have also used this command: bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off. Still not working.

Comment: This might be related: [Neither updatable production driver nor prerelease driver is supported.](https://github.com/Igalia/wolvic/issues/357)